# How to handle slices of structs that encapsulate another type as parameters

Tags: go

I have two structs (Dimension and Metric) and part of their attributes overlap, so I decided to go with a common struct that is then encapsulated.

```
type Attribute struct {
    Function *string
    Id *string
}

type Dimension struct {
    Attribute
    Class *string
}

type Metric struct {
    Alias *string
    Attribute
}
```

What I would like is to have a function that takes a slice of either Dimensions or a slice of Metrics and sorts it by the `id` field, which is common between the two.

```
dimensions := []Dimension{...}
metrics := []Metric{...}
sortById(dimensions)
sortById(metrics)
```

I could use a slice of interface types `func sortItems(items []interface{})` but I would prefer to avoid this so I was wondering how I can do something like the lines below.

```
func sortItems(items []Attribute) {
    //Sort here
}
```

If I try this, I am getting `cannot use metrics (type []Metric) as type []Attribute in argument to this.sortItems` which is to be expected, but I am new enough to Go not to know how to approach this.

I know I could just create two functions (one for each type) but I am curious what the correct pattern is for tackling issues like these in Go.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an interface and have it be implemented by the common type `Attribute`.

Something like this:

```
type Attributer interface {
    GetId() *int
}

func (a Attribute) GetId() *int {
    return a.Id
}

func sortItems(items []Attributer) {
    //Sort here
}
```

By virtue of *embedding* the `Attribute` type, both `Dimension` and `Metric` can be used wherever the `Attributer` interface is expected.

So this will compile just fine.

```
items := []Attributer{Dimension{}, Metric{}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping I could somehow avoid having to write an interface but it makes sense.